# Is there difference between [precision] and [floating-accuracy]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I want to ask question about floating point value issues, but found 2 similar tags (I think) : [floating-point-precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point-precision) and [floating-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy).

[floating-point-precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point-precision) is remapped to [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision), so I guess [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision) refers to all data types and [floating-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy) is restricted to float only, is that right? And, should [floating-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy) also be remapped to [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision)?

Comment: Thinking that precision and accuracy are synonyms get a *lot* of programmers into trouble.  Making the tags synonymous would be a very drastic mistake.  Bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

These are different, but you could probably put an argument that the tag wikis need help.

*precision* refers to the range of numbers that can be represented - often quoted in terms of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) (or, when dealing with binary numbers, significant bits). *Accuracy* is related to numbers that are within that precision but still can't be represented exactly.

---

For example, an IEEE754 Double has 53 significant bits of mantissa precision (and 11 bits of exponent precision), giving (according to Wikipedia) 15-17 significant decimal figures. But the number one tenth (decimal 0.1), which with one significant decimal figure is *well* within that precision, can't be represented exactly as an IEEE754 Double.

---

You could argue that they are technically the same thing (0.1 requires infinitely many significant bits when stored in binary, and not enough bits is a precision thing), but they cause different types of problems that have different types of solutions.

Although various programming languages apply some magic to display the value 0.1 instead of 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, accuracy problems can cause cumulative errors in calculations:

```
>>> a = sum([0.1]*10)
>>> b = 0.1*10
>>> a
0.9999999999999999
>>> b
1.0
>>> a == b
False
```

The solution to these is to either:

- Rearrange your arithmetic to do less, bigger calculations (such as one multiplication instead of 10 additions), or
- Use a type that can accurately represent the values you care about (eg, a decimal float type or a fraction/rational type)

Precision problems will cause problems like overflow or underflow (overflowing IEEE754 operations tend to return ±infinity, but other numeric types might have different behavior like 'wrapping around'):

```
>>> m = sys.float_info.max
>>> m
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> 2*m
inf
```

The solution to these is to use a wider precision type, or even an unlimited precision type (like Python's `int` or Java's `BigInteger`, or extended precision floats like C's `long double`).

Answer (score 1):

There is very much a difference between precision and accuracy, as one of my answers on SO points out:

[What is the difference between 'precision' and 'accuracy'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270789/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-accuracy)

Although I'm having trouble envisaging where a developer would actually find in useful to discuss accuracy except in the context of precision, I don't think we should conflate the two since, after all, my inability to envisage such a situation is irrelevant as I'm not omniscient. Yet :-)